# Monitor Outlook startup/closure

Tags: c#, wmi, outlook-addin

You will find hereafter an extract of a class aiming at adding a button in Outlook context menu if Outlook is launched.
When outlook is not launched, a Start EventWatcher is armed to detect Outlook startup.
A Close EventWatcher is also armed to allow ressources clean-up when Outlook is closed.

I run this code in Admin mode but the application randomly crashes. If I disable all the code around EventWatchers it's stable. I can't find the origin of these crashes, can you help me ? (Forgive me for the french comments in the text).

The entry point is the tryHook method.

```
public class OutlookIF
{
    // Attributs métiers       
    private Outlook.Application outlook = null;

    // Process watch
    private ManagementEventWatcher startWatch =
        new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName = 'OUTLOOK.EXE'"));
    private ManagementEventWatcher stopWatch =
        new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessName = 'OUTLOOK.EXE'"));      

    // Gestion du singleton
    private static OutlookIF v_instance = null;
    public static OutlookIF Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (v_instance == null)
                v_instance = new OutlookIF();

            return v_instance;
        }
    }

    private OutlookIF()
    {
        // Récupération des évènements EventArrived
        startWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatch_EventArrived);
        stopWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(stopWatch_EventArrived);         
    }

    // Vérification de la présence d'un process Outlook running
    private bool outlookIsLaunched = (Process.GetProcessesByName("outlook").Count() > 0);

    //Tentative de connexion à Outlook
    public void tryHook()
    {
        if (this.outlookIsLaunched)
        {
            this.hookOutlook();
            this.stopWatch.Start();
        }
        else
            this.startWatch.Start();     
    }

    // Ajout du menu contextuel à Outlook
    private void hookOutlook()
    {
        // Création de l'objet application
        if (this.outlookIsLaunched)
            this.outlook = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
        else
            this.outlook = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();

        // Création de l'entrée dans le menu contextuel           
        this.outlook.ItemContextMenuDisplay += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(addEntrytoContextMenu);          
    }

    // Nettoyage des objets
    private void clean()
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(this.outlook); 
        this.outlook = null;
    }

    private void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Arrêt de l'écoute de l'ouverture
        this.startWatch.Stop();

        TrayIcon.afficheMessage("ProcessWatch", "Ouverture d'Outlook");           
        this.hookOutlook();

        // Démarrage de l'écoute de la fermeture
        this.stopWatch.Start();
    }

    private void stopWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Arrêt de l'écoute de la fermeture
        this.stopWatch.Stop();

        TrayIcon.afficheMessage("ProcessWatch", "Fermeture d'Outlook");           
        this.clean();

        // Démarrage de l'écoute de l'ouverture
        this.startWatch.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified the code and put it in a thread and it seems to work.
Nevertheless there is a huge drawback: Oulook and the program shall both run in Admin mode.
I am open to new propositions less restrictive.

Here is the thread creation:

```
Thread outlThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OutlookIF.Instance.tryHook));
        outlThread.Start();
```

And the new class:

```
public class OutlookIF
{
    // Attributs métiers       
    private Outlook.Application outlook;
    private String messageIDParam = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E";

    // Process watch
    private ManagementEventWatcher startWatch;
    private ManagementEventWatcher stopWatch;

    // Static Initialization Singleton Pattern
    private static readonly OutlookIF v_instance = new OutlookIF();
    public static OutlookIF Instance{get{return v_instance;}}

    private OutlookIF()
    {
        // Création des processWatchers
        startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName = 'OUTLOOK.EXE'"));
        stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessName = 'OUTLOOK.EXE'"));      
    }

    //Tentative de connexion à Outlook
    public void tryHook()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName("outlook").Length == 0)
                startWatch.WaitForNextEvent();

            try
            {
                this.outlook = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();      
                this.outlook.ItemContextMenuDisplay += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(addEntrytoContextMenu);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

            stopWatch.WaitForNextEvent();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(this.outlook);
            this.outlook = null;
        }  
    }
}
```